# How to handle bookmarkable URLs in Vaadin7?

Tags: url, vaadin, vaadin7

How to handle bookmarkable URLs in Vaadin7?

Let's say enter the following URL:

```
https://HOST/SERVLET/Parameters
```

but `event.getRequest().getContextPath()` leaves the parameters out.
So anything beyond SERVLET is swallowed by Vaadin. 
So how can I access the missing part?

Moreover the parameters should appear as part of the URL and if I programmatically modify the parameters the users should get a different (updated) URL. In other words URL with unique and arbitrary parameters become bookmarkable.

The parameters are arbitrary and dynamic, need to be processed, and should be accessible within the session.

How can I force Vaadin to display such URLs that include the parameter value?

Comment: Have you checked though about usijng a Navigator or UriFragmentChangedListener?

Answer (score 0):

The `request.getContextPath()` will always give you the servlet context path, ie the `/SERVLET/` part only. If you want to get the parameters part only use `request.getPathInfo()`.

You have also `request.getRequestURI()` and `request.getRequestURL()` to get both paths and the server view of the full URL.

If you want to access to the browser location, use `Page.getCurrent().getLocation()` or `Page.getCurrent().setLocation()`